# Downloading data from firebase and store it locally using flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, dart

I have data in the format of string(firebase store data in format of string I mean) example:
{
'title': ABC
'Content': ---------
}
this is the data I have in my firebase now I want to make the user choose what to download and save it in the app(so that they may not be required to download next time). I want to make the title appear using a list view and showing a download icon side of the tile. So if they click then they can download and view it for later.
You may see the below image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBwNc.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can hive to store the data locally in the device in document format. Check out the documentation of hive
https://docs.hivedb.dev